# is that possible to proceed until some pixel has been changed?

Tags: autohotkey

!aa::
opteration 1  // the state of window changes to not ready
wait util color of arrow changed do operation 2  // after a while, the state become ready, and operation 2 should be executed after the window state is ready

at first, the window is not ready, 
[image]

i know there are AHK commands such as keywait, closewait, etc
but is there any command which wait the state of some pixel?
and is that possible to proceed until some pixel has been changed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [PixelGetColor](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/PixelGetColor.htm) command. It will give you current color of the pixel. To wait for some pixel to change color,  loop the [PixelGetColor](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/PixelGetColor.htm) command and comparison of the result that you get.

Here is some code:

```
x:= 600 ;x coordinate of pixel to check.
y:= 600 ;y coordinate of pixel to check.
targetcolor:= 0xffffff ;color to be matched in hexadecimal blue-green-red (BGR) format.

Loop
{
    PixelGetColor, currentcolor, x, y
    if (currentcolor=targetcolor)
    {
        ;do something
    }
    else
    {
        ;do something
    }
}
```

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*

Comment: is that possible to compute average pixel value of some region? since it is not stable to specify a fixed pixel in this scenario.

Comment: @crazyminer Since you now know `PixelGetColor`, why wouldn't it possible? Have you tried it?